# JQuery Mobile make a list item <li> blue after pressed and disable all links of the page

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, hyperlink

I'm writing a web app and I defined a List of elements.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
        <li>
           One  
        </li>
        <li>
           Two
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I need to make the selected item of the list < li > blue (like in iOS). On jQuery samples this works fine but can't make it happen on my code.

I also need to disable all the links of the page once the next page is loading. What is the best way to do this? Add an unclickable div on top or just write a JS that removes all the < a > tags, restore the AJAX spinner or something else?

Answer (score 3):

For the text color, you need to override the JQuery Mobile css. add your own css below the link to JQM css and paste this into it:

```
.ui-btn-up-c a.ui-link-inherit {
   color: -webkit-link;
}
```

regarding disabling links you can do:

```
$("li").addClass('ui-disabled');
$("a").attr('href','#');
```

This will show all list items as disabled and disable all links on your page.